# Exploring systems in Mass Effect 2

Tags: mass-effect-2

Is there any point in exploring systems that do not have a mission associated with them, besides resource gathering? For example are there any hidden side quests or random encounters to be found?

**EDIT:** To be more clear, are there any quests or random encounters which are not previously referred to or marked in any way, and thus can **only** be found by scanning planets? I have "found" a couple of missions by scanning planets but in each case the mission location was already marked on the system map.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes, there are some side quests that are not marked. If you scan a planet and find an anomaly there, this means there is a mission on that planet.

They are pretty short, but somewhat more varied than the side missions of Mass Effect 1.

According to the [Mass Effect 2 wiki](http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/Category:Anomaly) there are 38 anomalies that each represent a side mission (don't follow the link if you want to remain unspoiled).

Comment: I assume "systems that do not have a mission associated with them" means the side quests, which *are* in fact marked, but only after being discovered.

Comment: Yes I meant missions that you would not find if you didn't scan random planets, see my edit to the question.

Answer (score 7):

If EDI does not tell you when you first zoom in on a planet that "an anomaly has been detected", the planet can safely be ignored.

Unlike in Mass Effect 1, there are no hidden objects to search for (i.e., carbonaceous asteroids) either.